# Looking to group array by values in the sub array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

Trying to parse one data set that has a bunch of the same "secondaryIDs" in way that i can group and iterate through them together.

In english what im trying to do is 
"select a unique group of all items where the value of field is unique "

```
'use strict';

const data = [{
    Group: 'A',
    Name: 'SD'
}, {
    Group: 'B',
    Name: 'FI'
}, {
    Group: 'A',
    Name: 'MM'
}, {
    Group: 'B',
    Name: 'CO'
}];

let unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.Group))];
console.log(unique);
```

Which gives  ["A"],["B"]

but what im looking for is

```
{
  A: [ "SD","MM" ],
  B: [ "FI","CO" ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I would use `array.reduce` instead of `array.map` because what you're actually hoping to return is a *new* value, not a modified array, the reduce method is perfect when you want to literally reduce the array into a single output value, in your case an object of unique groups. Maybe try something like this:

```
let unique = data.reduce((acc, { Group, Name }) => {
  if (!(acc.hasOwnProperty(Group))) {
    acc[Group] = [Name];
  } else {
    acc[Group].push(Name);
  }; 
  return acc;
}, {});
```

I've also added a pen for this at: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BGpgdz?editors=1011 so you can see this working.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can also `reduce` your array to the grouped object (keyed by `Group` values):

```js
const data = [{
  Group: 'A',
  Name: 'SD'
}, {
  Group: 'B',
  Name: 'FI'
}, {
  Group: 'A',
  Name: 'MM'
}, {
  Group: 'B',
  Name: 'CO'
}];

const grouped = data.reduce((a, {Group, Name}) => {
  if (!(Group in a)) a[Group] = [Name];
  else a[Group].push(Name);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 0):

can do something like..

```
const map = {};
data.forEach( d => {
    if( map[d.Group] ) {
        map[d.Group].push(d.Name);
    } else {
        map[d.Group] = [d.Name];
    }
})
console.log(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be to use `Array.prototype.reduce` method to create an object that maps unique `Group` names to arrays that contain `Name`s. You can supply an empty object literal as your initial `reduce` accumulator:

```js
const data = [{
  Group: 'A',
  Name: 'SD'
}, {
  Group: 'B',
  Name: 'FI'
}, {
  Group: 'A',
  Name: 'MM'
}, {
  Group: 'B',
  Name: 'CO'
}];

var namesByGroup = data.reduce((map, el) => {
  map[el.Group] ? map[el.Group].push(el.Name) : map[el.Group] = [el.Name];
  return map;
}, {});

console.log(namesByGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a functional approach, here is a solution using Ramda:

```js
const group =
  R.pipe(
    R.groupBy(R.prop('Group')),
    R.map(R.map(R.prop('Name'))));

console.log(
  group([
    {Group: 'A', Name: 'SD'},
    {Group: 'B', Name: 'FI'},
    {Group: 'A', Name: 'MM'},
    {Group: 'B', Name: 'CO'}])
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

can also be done using forEach

```js
const data = [{
 Group: 'A',
 Name: 'SD'
}, {
 Group: 'B',
 Name: 'FI'
}, {
 Group: 'A',
 Name: 'MM'
}, {
 Group: 'B',
 Name: 'CO'
}];

const somefunction = (data) => {
let arr = {}
data.forEach( ({Group, Name}) => {
  Group in arr ?  arr[Group].push(Name) : arr[Group] = [Name]
})
return arr;
}

console.log(somefunction(data))
```